# Множественная вставка с помощью pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Подскажите, как сделать множественный `insert` с помощью `pdo`?

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pass');
$rows = [];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (type,sku,name,published,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$rows = [
    ['type' => 'fas', 'sku'=>'afds','name'=>'afsd','published'=>1,'description'=>'adsfasf'],
    ['type' => 'fas', 'sku'=>'afds','name'=>'afsd','published'=>1,'description'=>'adsfasf'],
];
$stmt->execute($rows);
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

**EDITED**

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,hide_from_product_page,custom_options,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,associated_skus
24-WG085,,Default,simple,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Sprite Yoga Strap 6 foot,"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.</p><ul><li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,,,,sprite-yoga-strap-6-foot,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta3",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=1,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,"24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086",,"name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Gold|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=,option_title=Silver|name=Custom Yoga Option,type=drop_down,required=0,price=10.0000,price_type=fixed,sku=yoga3sku,option_title=Platinum",,,,,,
24-WG086,,Default,simple,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Sprite Yoga Strap 8 foot,"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and durable under strain.</p><ul><li>8' long x 1.0"" wide.<li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",17,,,,sprite-yoga-strap-8-foot,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta4",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,24-WG087,24-WG087,24-WG087,,,,,,,,
24-WG087,,Default,simple,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Sprite Yoga Strap 10 foot,"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and durable under strain.</p><ul><li>10' long x 1.0"" wide.<li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",21,,,,sprite-yoga-strap-10-foot,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta5",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",100,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,24-WG086,24-WG086,24-WG086,,,,,,,,
24-WG085_Group,,Default,grouped,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Set of Sprite Yoga Straps,"<p>Great set of Sprite Yoga Straps for every stretch and hold you need. There are three straps in this set: 6', 8' and 10'.</p><ul><li>100% soft and durable cotton.</li><li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.</li><li>Choice of three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</li></ul>",,,1,,"Catalog, Search",,,,,set-of-sprite-yoga-straps,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta6",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,"24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086",,,,,,,,"24-WG085=5.0000,24-WG086=5.0000"
24-WG085-bundle-dynamic,,Default,bundle,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Sprite Yoga Strap Dynamic Bundle,"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and durable under strain.</p><ul><li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,,,,sprite-yoga-strap2,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta8",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=1,shipment_type=together,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,"24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086",,,dynamic,dynamic,Price range,fixed,"name=Bundle Option One1,type=select,required=1,sku=24-WG085,price=15.0000,default=0,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed|name=Bundle Option One1,type=select,required=1,sku=24-WG086,price=10.0000,default=1,default_qty=1.0000,price_type=fixed",
24-WG085-bundle-fixed,,Default,bundle,"Default Category/Gear,Default Category/Gear/Fitness Equipment",base,Sprite Yoga Strap Fixed Bundle,"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and durable under strain.</p><ul><li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>",,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",14,,,,sprite-yoga-strap3,Meta Title,"meta1, meta2, meta9",meta description,"2015-10-25 03:34:20","2015-10-25 03:34:20",,,Block after Info Column,,,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=1,shipment_type=together,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,"24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086","24-WG087,24-WG086",,,fixed,fixed,Price range,fixed,"name=Yoga Strap,type=radio,required=1,sku=24-WG086,price=0.0000,default=1,default_qty=3.0000,price_type=percent|name=Yoga Strap,type=radio,required=1,sku=24-WG085,price=0.0000,default=0,default_qty=3.0000,price_type=percent",
```

вот пример строки из-за которой не работает `insert`:

```
"<p>The Sprite Yoga Strap is your untiring partner in demanding stretches, holds and alignment routines. The strap's 100% organic cotton fabric is woven tightly to form a soft, textured yet non-slip surface. The plastic clasp buckle is easily adjustable, lightweight and urable under strain.</p><ul><li>100% soft and durable cotton.<li>Plastic cinch buckle is easy to use.<li>Three natural colors made from phthalate and heavy metal free dyes.</ul>"
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то массив должен быть одномерным

Comment: @Pashok, это не работает  $rows = ['fasdf','afsdfafsd','afsdfsa',1,'asffads','fasdf','afsdfafsd','afsdfsa',1,'asffads']; $stmt->execute($rows);

Comment: A обязательно 1 execute? если много execute в одной транзакции -- тоже быстрей.

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, а для чего здесь применять транзакции?

Comment: @word, чтобы инсерты отработали атомарно и быстрей; `$dbh->beginTransaction();...$dbh->commit();`; https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, а это разве не будет вызывать многократно insert into.. insert into... ?

Comment: @word, будет; но это может пререстать быть проблемой; а какая DB?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, db - mariadb 10.3

Comment: "но это может пререстать быть проблемой" что это значит?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, "будет"  , тогда ведь это не правильное решение. Вы хотя-бы знаете как сделать правильно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112552/discussion-between-sergei-kirjanov-and-word).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно всего лишь решить для себя, **какие плейсхолдеры используются в запросе** - именованные или позиционные.

В запросе написаны позиционные, а в execute() передаётся ассоциативный массив как для именованных.

Как только эта сложнейшая задача будет решена, остальное будет уже делом техники. Пример можно взять [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert#multiple)

```
$rows = [
    ['type' => 'fas', 'sku'=>'afds','name'=>'afsd','published'=>1,'description'=>'adsfasf'],
    ['type' => 'fas', 'sku'=>'afds','name'=>'afsd','published'=>1,'description'=>'adsfasf'],
];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (type,sku,name,published,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$pdo->beginTransaction();
foreach ($rows as $data)
{
    $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
}
$pdo->commit();
```

стильно, модно, молодёжно
(и никакого камалания с бубном, $pdo->quote и htmlspecialchars)

Comment: подскажите, если по предложенному вами способу с помощью транзакций в цикле запустить 1000 insert, т.е. $rows содержит 1000 строк данных, и запустить эти же 1000 строк без транзакций, будет ли разница в скорости обработки 1000 строк с транзакциями и без них?

Comment: да, разница будет

Comment: это будет то же самое, если запустить insert с 1000 строк, но одним запросом? как-то так: `insert into table (...) values( (row1),(row2),... (row1000) )`

Comment: если с транзакцией, то будет то же самое

Comment: 1) лучше бы именованные плейсхолдеры, ошибиться с порядком сложней
2) с транзакцией -- _примерно_ то же самое

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать обертку:

```
function multi_insert($dbh, $table, $fields, $data){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $d){
        $keys = [];
        foreach($fields as $fn){
            $key = ':i'.$i.$fn;
            $keys[] = $key;
            $param[$key] = $d[$fn];
        }
        $stm_texts[] = '('.implode(',',$keys).')';
        $i++;
    }     
    $stm_text = 'insert into '.$table.' ('.implode(',',$fields).') values '.implode(',',$stm_texts);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($stm_text);
    $stmt->execute($param);
}
```

Пример:

```
multi_insert($dbh, "messages", ["id","title","message"], [
    ["id"=>1,"title"=>"a","message"=>"am"],
    ["id"=>2,"title"=>"b","message"=>"bm"],
    ["id"=>3,"title"=>"c","message"=>"cm"],
]);
```

---

Есть также вариант использовать транзакции, т. к. объем одного запроса может быть ограничен. Транзакции обеспечивают атомарность и дают большую скорость.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
...
$dbh->commit();
```

В любом случае: измеряйте->оптимизируйте->измеряйте.

---

В аргументы `$table` и `$fields` передаются константы. Из них будет склеен результирующий запрос. Передача в них произвольных данных может привести к **взлому** системы.

Comment: благодарю, ваш код работает. но есть проблема скорее в csv, добавил в вопрос csv, подскажите, код перестаёт работать, когда обрабатывается поле `description`, 7-е по счёту от начала. Что не так в этом поле подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: пытался экранировать с помощью `$pdo->quote` и `htmlspecialchars` всё-равно не работает для поля `description`

Comment: @word это ткод повторяет очень частую ошибку из-за которой запрос становится открыт для SQLЧ инъекций, через ключи массива с данными.

Comment: @Ипатьев, "этот" какой, в вопросе или ответе?  пример инъекции можно?

Comment: Ну наверное если я комментирую ответ, то в ответе. пример можно посмотреть например [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#injection)

Comment: @Ипатьев, в примере по ссылке итерация идет по ключам POST-а; а в моем примере специально для такого случая передается _константный_ массив ключей

Comment: уязвимость в предлагаемой **обёртке**. кто там куда что итерирует - вопрос тридцать десятый. все эти пространные рассуждения "если применять вот с таким подвыподвером, то всё бизапасна, насяльника!" - это такой детский лепет, что уши вянут. с такой логикой можно и подготовленные выражения не использовать, оправданий можно найти кучу, например популярное "у миня интранет, некому взламывать будет!". Все эти детские "понарошку" являются **внешними** и необязательными для предлагаемого кода условиями. Для сравнения посмотри на плейсхолдеры - как ты их не пиши, инъекции не будет.

Comment: @Ипатьев, тогда (по вашему) в самом `$dbh->prepare` тоже уязвимость, т. к. в него с дуру можно передать текст запроса из `$_POST`

Comment: да, так оно и есть. спорь дальше.